# Need PHP dropdown with result shown in text box

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and getting data from mysql. I would like to have a dropdown of countries and then when the country is selected then the prefix must be the result either in a text box on the same line or just below the dropdown box.

so far my code gives me the prefix concatenated  with prefix eg

Zimbabwe-263

here is the code

```
  <?php 

include 'config.php';

   $query="SELECT countryname, countryprefix FROM cc_country";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $options="";
echo "<select name='processor' value=''>
    <option>Select A Country</option>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<option value='".$nt['countryprefix']."'>".$nt['countryname']."-".$nt['countryprefix']."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: I don't get how exactly you want it to behave. You want another text field to appear when something is selected from the drop down?

Comment: You can use Jquery..

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selected value to display in textbox you can use jquery for that.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sctipt>
    $('select').change(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    $('#text').val(value);
    });
</script>
```

Create a textbox with id text for this

Comment: i dont really know jquery do you mean i must add   below my code??       $('select').change(function(){
var value=$(this).val();
$('#text').val(value);
});

Comment: I will edit my code add that code in your file and it would work

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fire another query that will fetch the country prefix on selection of the country.That is pass the value of your select box to he sql query.You can do this using **jquery or javascript** by giving an id to the select box you are using .

```
           var countryname = $('#yourId').val();
```

then do a ajax or jquery post to a PHP file which will have the blow query.
For example:

```
 $query="SELECT countryprefix FROM cc_country where countryname='your post value";
```

then below your while loop add a text field which will display the value returned by your above query

Comment: i understand only php as i am still learning cant i display this using only php??

Comment: You can but it is not the right way to do. PHP is server side so it will make a page refresh as you will need to send a new request when you change the country value. `Javascript`,`jquery` and `ajax` are meant for the same purpose that you are trying to achive which is asynchronous request.So learn it and then go ahead would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.textbox').val(value); // html <input type="text" class="textbox">
 });
```